# How should we manage per-site parameters, in asp.net 5.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We're trying to move a fairly complicated set of web applications from .NET 4.5 to .NET 5.0, hosted in IIS.

One problem we need to figure out is how to manage the per-environment configuration, during deploys.

With .NET 4.5 we are using web deploy packages. The production team already has hundreds of xxx.SetParameters.xml files for the many customers and environments.

In dev and test, we're using appsettings.%ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%.json, but that's not going to work for our production deploys.

The production team would like to continue using web deploy packages with xxx.Parameters.xml and xxx.SetParameters.xml files, so they don't have to reconstruct them in some new mechanism.

We're fine with telling them they have to change, if they really do have to change.

How are per-environment configuration settings usually managed, in asp.net 5.0?

---

Some additional clarification.

In our existing process, a build generates a deployment package.

A deploy to a particular environment then takes that package and a file defining the configuration for that particular environment, and creates a site and applies that configuration.

This is currently using msdeploy, but that's not important. What is important is that the per-environment configuration files are maintained in a separate repository, and are *not* stored with the source code.

And we don't want them to be.

The change history of the per-environment configuration files is completely unrelated to the change history of the source code used to create the deploy packages.

Comment: _“but that's not going to work for our production deploys”_ – Why not? That being said, there is an [XML configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#xml-configuration-provider) you could use if you want stick to XML. But IIS based application configuration _will not work_ with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Why not? Because we have hundreds of environments, some on premises and some off, and for the prod team to have to go back to the dev team to push a commit every time something changes is unacceptable overhead.

Comment: all the settings for in the appsettings.json file... these files are applied in order one on top of the other. since you already automated how to pull those files... it is very simple the same logic that selects the appropriate production file will just have to rename the file to appsettings.json without any environment which is the first file that loads.

Comment: What I've been considering is having an appsettings.json with the base settings, an appsettings.prod_sample.json, that is not used but can provide the prod team with an example of what things should look like, and an appsettings.prod.json file that is empty, and will be replaced on deploy.

And then setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "prod" in the production web.config, so that it won't be dependent upon the server's system-level configuration.

Comment: You do not need to have _environment-specific_ files in your repository. So yes, you can have hundreds of `appsettings.envname.json` files (instead of your XML files) and apply pretty much the same way you have been working before.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about having hundreds of different filenames. I was thinking about having hundreds of different files, each with the same name, and have the pipeline copy the correct one for the environment it's deploying to.

Comment: Then use just a single environment name (e.g. “Production” since that is the default environment), name your files `appsettings.Production.json` and do exactly that.